# Javascript / Jquery - Variable in Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, variables

The array `replaceThis` is user generated so i cant write constant regex rules.
But how can i create the regex rules? 
Any ideas for a nice solution?

```
var replaceThis = new Array();
replaceThis[0] = ':)';
replaceThis[1] = 'XD';
replaceThis[2] = '-.-';
replaceThis[3] = 'hello world';
replaceThis[3] = ' a ';        
replaceThis[3] = ' B ';                

var message = 'text text :) text text -.- and hello world XD and text a btext B text text';
$.each(replaceThis, function(i)
{
    var regex = new RegExp (" ??? ","gi");
    message = message.replace(regex,'<span class="blue">'+????+'</span>');
});

$('body').append(message+'<hr/>');
```

**Playground:** http://jsfiddle.net/s7b3r/2/

Thanks in advance!
Jamie

Comment: What do you need to do? Wrap those strings in a `<span>`?

Comment: So you need to escape your regex so that `new RegExp ("(:))","gi")` does not break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Check the working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7b3r/5/)***.

You need to escape the special chars for regex.

```
String.prototype.escapeRegExp = function() {
  return this.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$.each(replaceThis, function(i, data){
    var regex = new RegExp(data.escapeRegExp(),"gi");
    message = message.replace(regex, '<span class="blue">$&</span>'); 
});
```